# Attach to an already running shell on another machine

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have a shell (PID 123) running on a Linux terminal on Machine A. I'm currently working on Machine B in another room/city/country and am able to SSH into Machine A. But is there a way to take control of shell/process 123 on Machine A?

Answer (score 1):

`reptyr` is made to do exactly this: https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr

A blog post by its author, including links to related things like `screenify`, is here: https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/